# What to do if being sent hundreds of 4-digit verification codes

Tags: android

Recently I was sent a WhatsApp verification code, though I did not ask for it. Later a scammer ask for the code, saying they "accidentaly" sent it to me. Now I am sent MojiLaLa verification codes. (I do not have that app installed.)

They are 4 digits codes, and I was just sent hundreds of it. So there is a good chance that the attacker managed to use it well for whatever purpose they had. What should I do about this?

Comment: What do you want to do? What effect would you like to have? Have you contacted MojiLaLa  support?

Comment: did you give the scammer the code?

Comment: @schroeder, yes, I should improve this question.

Comment: @Jasen, no, I haven't.